# Is it legal or illegal to record my communication with my landlord in public parking area in Canada?

Tags: canada, recording

Is it legal or illegal to record my communication with my landlord in public parking area in Canada?

- if I didn't tell my landlord that I am going to record.
- if I tell my landlord I am recording but he didn't give me a clearly answer.

Please let me know if it is illegal. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I am not from Canada but in the US as long as it is not a completely one-sided conversation, realistically it is not against the law. If you were intending to just tape him talking or a conversation between him and someone else, then it would be illegal. My question would be why are you wanting to tape him and what are you intending to do with this tape? There is a reason that you are wanting to do it.

Comment: This is misleading and in some states outright false. There are a number of "two-party" and even "all-party" jurisdictions in the USA.